# Can we perform meta-analysis of successive but independent studies?

Tags: meta-analysis

I measured a variable $X$ and estimated the error bars on my measurement with the objective of testing if $X$ is significantly different from zero. 
I concluded that $X$ is different from zero only at 2$\sigma$. Following this, I applied the same technique and made use of an (arguably) more precise instrument, and made a second independent measurement. Unfortunately, I concluded that this second measurement is different from zero only at 2$\sigma$ as well.

Is it legit to combine the two consecutive measurements? How can this be done?

Comment: You can easily perform meta-analysis of correlated data with mvmeta in R or Stata. Also consider using individual data meta-analysis though, accounting for clustering.

Comment: Since you have the original data why not just do a single analysis with measurement technique as a possible covariate? Or have I mis-understood your design?

Comment: By covariate do you mean control variable? Or do you mean something different? https://www.theanalysisfactor.com/confusing-statistical-terms-5-covariate/

Note that the objective is to get a global picture (and potentially reach a higher level of significance) using the meta analysis. Will including a covariate help?

Comment: I mean a variable which distinguishes the two measurement types.